# How to avoid stackoverflow error for n = 8 in N Rooks problem

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, backtracking

I want to solve **N** Rooks problem in **N x N** board using recursion with max **N** = *8*. My code works fine for **N** = *2*, *3*, *4*, *5*, *6*, *7*. But when **N** = *8* it gives so many possible results starting with the first row of **1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0** then gives ***stackoverflow error*** before checking other possible results starting with the first row of **0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0**.

I know about general recursion like *fibonacci series*, *factorial*, etc. and I can trace them down. Then I came across a new form of recursion called backtracking recursion. Then I sarted to learn the logic behind this form of recursion and read some pseudocode algorithms. Acually this form of recursion seemed to me a little bit harder to construct than normal recursion.

```
public class NRooks {
/**
 * In this code r = which row, c = which column.
 * lastY method just returns column c of last placed rook in
 * a given row r in order to remove it.
 * row.length, col.length, board.length have no special meaning. They all
 * equal to the dimension of board N.
 * main() method always initiates first row(r = 0). Therefore in main()
 * method r remains 0 and c changes as you can see in putRook(0, i). 
 * So solve() method always begins from second row(r = 1).
 */

private static int found = 0;
private static int[][] board;
private static int[] row;
private static int[] col;

public static void putRook(int r, int c) {
    board[r][c] = 1;
    row[r]  = 1;
    col[c]  = 1;
}

public static void removeRook(int r, int c) {
    board[r][c] = 0;
    row[r]  = 0;
    col[c]  = 0;
}

public static boolean isValid(int r, int c) {
    if (row[r] == 0 && col[c] == 0) return true;
    return false;
}

public static void showBoard() {
    for (int r = 0; r < board.length; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < board.length; c++) {
            System.out.print(board[r][c] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();
}

public static int lastY(int r) {
    for (int j = 0; j < board.length; j++) {
        if (board[r][j] == 1) return j;
    }
    return -1;
}


public static boolean solve(int r, int c) {
    int last;

    if (r == 0) return false;

    if (r == col.length) {
        found++;
        /**
         * When I dont include below printline statement my code 
         * works fine until N = 7 then gives SO error.
         * But When I include this print statement in order
         * to print number of results my code works fine until
         * N = 6 then gives SO error
         */
        //System.out.println("Found: " + found);
        showBoard();
        r--;
        last = lastY(r);
        removeRook(r, last);
        c = last + 1;
    }

    for (int j = c; j < row.length; j++) {
        if (isValid(r, j)) {
            putRook(r, j);
            return solve(r + 1, 0);
        }
    }

    last = lastY(r - 1);
    removeRook(r - 1, last);
    return solve(r - 1, last + 1);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    board = new int[n][n];
    row = new int[n];
    col = new int[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
        boolean finished; // not important
        putRook(0, i);
        finished = solve(1, 0);
        if (finished) System.out.println("============"); // ignore this too
    }
}
}
```

***Stackoverflow*** points to the lines that contain recursive calls to **solve()** method.

*Note:* I know only **C** like syntax of java and basic data abstraction. I wrote this code with this level of my **Java**.

I want to solve this problem and N queens problem myself. 
Because there are so many solutions to these problems out there, both mathematically and algorithmically. And I am not interested in advanced **Java** *data abstraction* things right now.
I only want some advice about my code snippet above something like

- Your backtracking algorithm is not efficient. (so straightfoward)
- You need to use some **Java** data abstraction things to solve this problem efficiently.
- You need to use another form of recursion like *tail recursion* (I heard about this too.)
- ....

Comment: Have you checked what `r` is in each recursive call? If you're getting a SO, either the problem is too large to solve recursively, or the logic is flawed and the base case is never being reached. Java currently doesn't have tail call optimization, so if it ends up being the former, you may need to rethink your algorithm.

Comment: Step away from "running the code" for a moment, and take a piece of paper and a pen, and then look at what happens to your `r` as you run through this function. _very specifically_ what happens to it when `r == col.length`. What values can `r` take on? And what does that mean for that terminal condition? Is it actually correct?

Comment: I suspect that there is a flaw in your logic. `N=8` shouldn't be too large for an overflow because you should only recurse 8 calls deep if implemented correctly. Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on debugging your code to find your error.

Comment: Your `for` loop looks suspicious to me. A recursive solution shouldn't need any for loop. I also agree with @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans that you should step away from the code and work things out by hand.

Comment: Question: what is the purpose of this code? Do you want to find **one** solution to the problem? Or do you want to find **all** solutions?

Comment: I want to find all solutions. For example this code gives 3! = 6 results for N = 3 , 4! = 24 results for N = 4 and tested for N = 7 but did not count exact number, I just assumed that it gave correct number of results for N = 7 because program terminates normally with a txt file of results which has over 40k lines. To be sure I can add a line of code that counts number of different results.

Comment: I'll be happy to take a shot at this when the code is complete.  As @Code-Apprentice already pointed out, there isn't any reason to go deeper than 8 calls: by then, you hit the opposite edge of the board.  Trace the call sequence, both by hand and by your main debugging weapon, tracing output.  Also document your program so we know what you *think* you're doing at each block.

Comment: The very best way to prevent stack overflow when you are implementing a recursive solution is to stop implementing a recursive solution and implement a linear solution instead.  The rooks problem does not require a recursive solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue why you're getting Stack Overflow error is the way your recursion is structured. The moment `solve` is invoked in the `main` method, it keeps recursing deeper and deeper; in fact, all of its invocations form a single several-thousand-calls-deep chain. For n=7, there are 3193 nested calls (I added a counter to check this). For n=8, it performs about 5k recursive calls before overflowing stack on my machine - I guess stack size is rather small by default.

Thus, to get this to work for higher values of n, you need to restructure your recursion in a way that doesn't perform all the recursive calls as a single chain. I could argue that your current solution isn't really backtracking because it never actually backtracks. Let me illustrate what backtracking means on a simpler problem. Let's say you want to print all binary strings of length n=3 ("000" through "111") programmatically, without relying on knowing the value of n. An implementation for this could be something like this:

```
def build_binary_string(current_prefix, chars_left):
  if chars_left == 0:
    print current_prefix
    return
  build_binary_string(current_prefix + 'a', chars_left - 1)
  build_binary_string(current_prefix + 'b', chars_left - 1)

build_binary_string("", 3)
```

The interesting thing (backtracking!) happens at the moment when `build_binary_string` is invoked with arguments ("00", 1):

- `build_binary_string("000", 0)` is invoked, prints "000" and returns immediately
- we are back into `build_binary_string("00", 1)` function call, right about to execute `build_binary_string(current_prefix + 'b', chars_left - 1)`
- `build_binary_string("001", 0)` is invoked, prints "001" and returns immediately

That point when control flow returned from `build_binary_string("000", 0)` to `build_binary_string("00", 1)` and it chose to make another function call was backtracking. Note that the depth of recursion never exceeded 3.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot test your code as I do not have some of your methods, but is the int j = c supposed to be int j = r?

```
for (int j = c; j < row.length; j++) {
    if (isValid(row, col, r, j)) {
        putRook(b, row, col, r, j);
        return solve(b, row, col, r + 1, 0);
    }
}
```

Inside of this line you are passing 0 to c then declaring j=c in the for loop conditions so j < row.length will be true every time.  I do not know what your isValid() is though.

```
   return solve(b, row, col, r + 1, 0);
```

EDIT:  I see now the c is being declared in the if block above, but if that if block does not get executed this should be an infinite loop afterward.  Maybe check to see if r == col.length is executing correctly.